# Raspberry Pi Zero as a usb ethernet gadget but with networked storage

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, pi-zero, file-sharing

I'm attempting to emulate a USB ethernet gadget that, when connected to a PC, allows access to storage via its network. I was thinking that you might be able to make a samba file share or maybe an FTP server.

Comment: "through its network" - which one is "it" in this case? the pi or the pc?

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi Zero does not have a wired port to connect it direct to your network, so you always have to use an additional device with an USB port and a wired network port. As you noted you will connect the Pi Zero with an USB cable to the additional device and use OTG ethernet gadget mode to emulate an ethernet connection. On the other side you connect the additional device to your local network with its wired port or maybe by WiFi and route the network traffic to the samba share or FTP server on the RPi Zero. The additional device is just a router.

But at least now you should see that it does not make sense. You can simply have your samba share and FTP server on the additional device.

Comment: sort of an off-topic comment, but your use of "**an USB**" (as opposed to "**a USB**") piqued my interest. Turns out SE also has a site dedicated to usage of the English language, and here's what [one answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1017/304077) says about this question. I thought first, "OK, so I am correct because the article "a" is correct for both "Universal" and "U"... But then I realized: "Wait - how is that pronounced in German?" So - maybe that is correct after all  :)

Comment: @Seamus Seems I do not understood all the time the rule with the vowel **sound**, not with a vowel **letter** :-( Thanks for the link.

Comment: English is very [arcane](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/arcane), and this example proves it!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. What i did was used this GitHub project: https://github.com/RoganDawes/P4wnP1_aloa which let me easily change the USB gadget that i wanted to emulate. I than literally just set up samba. Also if i wasn't clear what i had wanted to do was be able to use the raspberry pi as a USB storage device but instead of just it emulating a USB storage drive it would pretend to be a USB Ethernet adapter with a file share that you could access from the attached PC.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.